# MP3/Audio/Podcast player for SharePoint Online/Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online

In legacy SharePoint it was possible to add a mp3 file to a site page and have a player for it where the user can play, pause, etc. for the given audio. Is there something similar to SharePoint Online Site pages - to add a mp3/audio file to a site page with a player/controller? MS Stream does not work as it only accepts video and we are not interested in converting all our audio to videos with a static background.

Answer (score 0):

We could use Embed web part in SharePoint online to add the mp3 file to a site page and user can play, pause as shown below:

[image]

Please note in my case I save the mp3 files in SiteAssets library.

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us